# Gridview bound to IQueryable LINQ query returns entire query instead of single page

Tags: linq-to-sql, gridview, pagination, business-logic-layer

I have a Business Layer class that uses LINQ to return IQueryable data to a GridView in the User Layer. I want it to return only a single page of data; however, it is returning the entire query. I have heard that paging should work, but every page turn brings back hundreds or thousands of rows and throws out all but the rows set in pagesize.

Here is the LINQ Query (edited down a bit)

```
        public IQueryable<ScoredMatch> List()
    {
        var dc = new PAQcDataLayerDataContext();
        var matches = (
            from m in dc.ScoredRecordMatches
            join c in dc.Customers on m.CustomerId equals c.CustomerId
            orderby m.PAQNumber
            select new ScoredMatch()
            {
                Id = m.Id,
                PAQId = (int)m.PAQId,
                PAQVersion = (int)m.PAQVersion,  
                JobTitleMatch = (bool)m.JobTitleMatch,
                OrgNameMatch = (bool)m.OrgNameMatch,
                IncumbentNameMatch = (bool)m.IncumbentNameMatch,
            });

        return matches;
    }
```

And here is the GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdMatches" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="gridview"
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="even" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" PageSize="10"
    DataKeyNames="Id" OnPageIndexChanging="grdMatches_PageIndexChanging" OnSorting="grdMatches_Sorting"
    AutoGenerateSelectButton="True" OnSelectedIndexChanging="grdMatches_SelectedIndexChanging">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PAQNumber" HeaderText="PAQ #" SortExpression="PAQNumber" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ScoredNumber" HeaderText="Score #" SortExpression="ScoredNumber" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerId" HeaderText="Cust #" SortExpression="CustomerId" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Customer" HeaderText="Customer" SortExpression="Customer" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Department" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DOTNumber" HeaderText="DOT #" SortExpression="DOTNumber" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="OrgNameMatch" HeaderText="Org Match" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="JobTitleMatch" HeaderText="Job Match" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IncumbentNameMatch" HeaderText="Inc Match" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is the code that loads the Gridview:

```
grdMatches.DataSource = new ScoredMatch().List();
grdMatches.DataBind();
```

And the code that does the paging:

```
   protected void grdMatches_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        grdMatches.DataSource = new ScoredMatch().List();
        grdMatches.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        grdMatches.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the current page you should use `Skip` and `Take` in your LINQ query to get just the results you want.

Eg:

```
 yourQuery.Skip((currentPage - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).Select(....
```

This will give you just the items that should be displayed in your result set and nothing else.

Check out the following article that will show you how to set it all up in more detail:

http://www.dbtutorials.com/display/linq-to-sql-paging-cs.aspx

Comment: I thought the gridview could be set up to handle paging all by its self?

Comment: @Nick it can but I think you can't just attach it to a raw List that is filtered (I could be wrong though).

Comment: Using @Kelsey's .Skip/.Take approach would require adding PageSize & CurrentPage to every query. If, as @Nick & I suspect, Linq is smart enough to figure this out, I want to learn how.

Comment: @Bob Jones for that to work you would need to be manipulating the query on the fly since you want the result from the DB to not have all the rows. That means you DataSource needs to be generating the linq as well for you which I have never done or know if it can be done.  I stay far away from using built in features to generate SQL.

Comment: @Bob, how is LINQ supposed to know what page you are on or how many records you want to return when you are manually invoking your method as a data source. You will need to provide that information via Skip() and Take(). If were instead to use a LinqData or ObjectData Source I believe some of that functionality will because more automatic.

Comment: If I undertand correctly, I cannot use an Object Data Source with a business layer. Love to know how.

Comment: @Bob Jones you will need to decouple it and/or at least pass in the paging params to your linq queries.  Nothing will generate the custom paging linq queries for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    protected void grdMatches_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        // not sure where to get "pageSize" with a grid view but would assume it is there someplace.
        grdMatches.DataSource = new ScoredMatch()
            .Skip(e.NewPageIndex * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize)
            .List();

        grdMatches.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        grdMatches.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Although @Andy Robinson's approach looks great on first glance, the initial load of the data only brings in "PageSize" rows and as a result, the GridView thinks it only has a single page of data and doesn't turn on paging.